# Setting up AWS S3 bucket permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, laravel-6

I have an S3 bucket (e.g. mybucket) which currently has permissions set as follows:

```
Block all public access
On
 |
 |_Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
 | On
 |
 |_Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
 | On
 |
 |_Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies
 | On
 |
 |_Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies
   On
```

Inside this bucket I have two folders:

```
 images  (e.g. https://mybucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/puppy.jpg)
 private (e.g. https://mybucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/private/mydoc.doc)
```

I want the images folder to be publicly accessible so that I can display images on my site.

I want the private folder to be restricted and can only be accessible using an IAM account programmatically.

How do I set these permissions? I've tried switching the above permissions off, I've also clicked on the images and unders actions, clicked on 'make public'. I then attempt the following to upload:

```
   $image = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(360, 180);
   Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, $image->stream());
```

File gets uploaded but when I try to display the image as follows I get 403 error:

```
   <img src="{{ Storage::disk('s3')->url($file->path) }}" />
```

And to download a private documents i have the following:

```
    $response =  [
        'Content-Type' => $file->mime_type,
        'Content-Length' => $file->size,
        'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
        'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename={$file->name}",
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
    ];

   
    return Response::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get($file->path), 200, $response);
```

What's the correct way to set up these permissions?

I'm new to S3 storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 Block Public Access is a bucket-level configuration that will prevent you making any of the objects in that bucket public. So, if you want to make one or more objects public, e.g. `images/*`, then you need to disable [S3 Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) for this bucket.

That, in and of itself, will not make any of your objects public, of course. S3 buckets are private by default. To make the objects in `images/` public, you will need to configure an S3 bucket policy, for example:

```
{
  "Id": "id101",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "publicimages",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/images/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. This seems to work. How do I secure the private folder with a policy that only the IAM user and account user can access . Do I need one since you mention making the bucket public doesn't make any of the object public anyway?

Comment: That bucket policy allows unauthenticated (i.e. public) access to `images/*` and nothing else. Independently, if you have IAM users with permissions that encompass this bucket (e.g. s3:* for all buckets) then they can access the bucket, independently of this bucket policy.